# Where can caching happen in the DNS hierarchy and how are queries forwarded?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, cache, terminology

For a hostname to resolve into its IP address, there are several DNS servers that may be queried. Assuming caching doesn't happen, it goes from whoever made the request (the client), the recursive DNS, the root DNS, the TLD DNS and finally the authoritative name server.

Do I have the order right? Are requests forwarded or does the server just reply with IP address of the server on the next level that should be contacted by the client? For example does the recursive name server do the actually querying on the root server or does it just pass the IP address of the root server along ? I'm guessing it's the first for caching purposes. Also, what stages can caching happen at, for example would the root server have a cached response from the TLD server? Since there's only 13 unique root servers, what is the point of having that level instead of just going directly to the TLD server?

Answer (score 2):

So this is a deep topic, so this is just the surface but consider that there are a couple ways that queries might be answered.

In general the type of query available will determine how many requests the client needs to make to resolve a path like `a.b.c.com`.

For Recursive resolution, the client queries the server once, for the full name being sought. The Server will handle the queries to the root servers, and then will resolve the Nameservers for `C` and then `B`, and will query `B` for the hostname `A`. the local server  will then send back a **single** response to the client.

For Non-recursive resolution, the client will send a request asking for the name servers for `C.com`, then query that server for the nameservers for `B.C.com`, and then query those servers for the host `A`. which is the actual answer we wanted all along. in this case though, the **client had to make 3 separate queries** to get it.

There is a related concept of "Forwarders", where a local resolver may forward unknown (non-local) queries up to another server for resolution. The interaction between the local server and the upstream resolver may be recursive or not, but the result is sent back to the client as a single response, so it is recursive from the clients perspective.

Now on the topic of Caching, the cache is most valuable from a network performance perspective the closer it is to the client. That said though, the trade-off is, that if the cache is too close, and represents a less-than-diverse set of cached answers, the cache may not be used very much. placing the cache a layer or two upstream, so that the cache represents the combined results of more users and thus is more likely to have answers can be of value.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have the order right?

The general order yes, but it is not a straight line: the root server doesn't forward your query anywhere else, it bounces back to the resolver with a referral response (telling the resolver to query elsewhere). Same goes for the TLD server and the domain server.

> Are requests forwarded or does the server just reply with IP address of the server on the next level that should be contacted by the client?

Both behaviors happen, but in different places.

> For example does the recursive name server do the actually querying on the root server or does it just pass the IP address of the root server along ?

The recursive server does the actual querying. This is literally what makes it a recursive server: after it has accepted the client's query, it will itself make further queries until it can return the final result. (That's because the client running on your OS is only a stub resolver which doesn't have all the necessary functionality.)

The root/TLD/domain servers, however, are not recursive – they only answer for the domains that they're authoritative for, and give only redirects (referrals) for the rest. They never make further queries on their own.

> Also, what stages can caching happen at, for example would the root server have a cached response from the TLD server?

Caching happens on systems which send queries and receive replies. This means that only recursive resolvers perform caching, because they receive cacheable information from someone else.

On the other hand, the root/TLD/domain servers never handle recursive queries – they don't query anything else, so there is nothing that they would need to cache. (They only answer for domains which they're *authoritative* about.)

> Since there's only 13 unique root servers, what is the point of having that level instead of just going directly to the TLD server?

How would everyone's resolvers know where the TLD servers are?

Keep in mind that there's no "the" TLD server. There are TLD servers for each TLD – e.g. the `com` TLD has one set of servers, the `eu` TLD has another. There are literally hundreds of TLDs, so a static list wouldn't do.

The DNS root simplifies this problem – instead of a list of all TLDs and their servers, there's only one root domain with its servers, which results in a much smaller initial list and one which changes *very* rarely, so resolver software could actually include a copy of it. Most recursive resolvers include a copy of the "root hints".

(Also, do note that there are 13 root server addresses because in the early days one address meant exactly one host, but that's no longer the case – the Internet supports anycast routing, so nearly each of those addresses actually corresponds to hundreds of unique instances in reality.)

Comment: When you use the name "domain server" what is it you are referring to, the recursive server? Wouldn't any server relating to DNS be accurately referred to as a domain server?

Comment: I was referring to the specific authoritative servers which hold data for the final domain (or subdomains; basically all the tiers after the TLD). As opposed to "TLD servers" which are the authoritative servers holding data for the TLD, or "root servers" which are authoritative for the DNS root.